# Prevent telerik window from Closing in onClose client event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, telerik, window

I am trying to display a confirm dialog when a user tries to close a window by click the 'X' in the top right corner. If the user goes for 'OK' option,  I would like to continue closing the window but if the user presses the 'Cancel' button I would like to prevent the window from closing. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Update: I looked at the window client events on : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window/clientsideevents. It says that the onClose event is cancellable but nowhere can I see how to cancel the event.

Comment: Doesn't anybody know how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Razor:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("Window")
    .ClientEvents(events =>
        .OnClose("preventClose")))

<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventClose(e)
    {
        var shouldClose = confirm("Are you sure you want to close?");

        if (!shouldClose)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tested and working. Note that this function is called when they click on the X or if you call `$("#Window").data("tWindow").close();` so unless you have some validation check like I demonstrated you won't be able to close the window. I don't see a way to distinguish between clicking on the X and calling `$(window).close()` manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer hawkke. For some odd reason I didn't see your answer today in the morning when I was looking if somebody answered to my problem. So I answered my own questions and marked it as an answer. But thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution to my problem on my own:

If you do `e.preventDefualt();` in the `onClose` event it would prevent the window from closing. There is a mention in the documentation that the `onClose` event is **cancellable** but nowhere does it say how to cancel the `onclose` event.